# How to ignore certain similar rows when select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table

```
Id  col1 col2 col3
1    c    2     m
2    c    3     6
2    b    d     u
3    e    6     9
4    1    v     8
4    2    b     t
4    4    5     g
```

As you can see, there are duplicate value in id column, 2 and 4. I only want to select rows with unique id value and ignore the following rows with duplicate id value. I just want to keep the first of the rows with duplicate values

```
1    c    2     m
2    c    3     6
3    e    6     9
4    1    v     8
```

There is FK constraint, so I cannot delete rows with duplicate values.

I am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Any reply will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to determine which of the duplicate rows that you want in the result? Is there any combination of fields that is guaranteed to be unique, for example `Id, Col1` so that it can be used as key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to number each row with the same `id`.  Then you can select only the first row per `id`:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by id order by col1, col2, col3) rn
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

The subquery is required because SQL Server doesn't allow `row_number` directly in the `where` clause.